# Como validar un texbox que solo me deje introducir numeros hasta el 100

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Cómo puedo validar un textbox para que no me deje introducir mayor a 100 en asp.net?.

Intente haciendo eso:

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("nota" + cont, item.nota, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = "0", max = "100", id = "txtNota", placeholder = "0" , onkeypress = "ValidarNumero(event)"})%>  



<script type="text/javascript">   
 document.addEventListener('keypress', ValidarNumero);        
    function ValidarNumero(numero) {                                                   
    if ((event.keyCode < 100) || (event.keyCode > 0))
       event.returnValue = true;
    else
       event.returnValue = false;
 }                  
</script>
```

pero solo me obtiene la tecla introducida y no asi las 2 o 3 teclas que se introducen... ayuda por fa

Comment: Te gustará probar con `parseInt(numero)`...

Comment: Estas usando DataAnnotations ?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que interpreté la validación la quieres hacer desde el lado del cliente, sería sencillo hacerla agregando un `EventListener` a `input`

Por ejemplo;

```
document.getElementById ("txtNota").addEventListener ("input", myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
  if(this.value > 100)
  {
    this.value = 100;
  }
}
```

Para ver como funciona, dejo el jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hL0fpyex/

Saludos y éxitos!

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que has utilizado DataAnnotations en tu modelo para validar, ejemplo `[Required]` para que el campo no sea null ó `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` para validar que el campo sea de tipo Fecha, también puedes crearte una Validación Personalizada, en este caso para que el número pasado sea menor que 100. Ejemplo

en tu carpeta Models crea una nueva clase de nombre MenorQue100Attribute con el siguiente código.

```
public class MenorQue100Attribute : ValidationAttribute
    {

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var numero = int.Parse(value.ToString());
            if (numero > 100)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage = "El número es mayor que 100");
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

y en tu modelo ya puedes agregar esa dataannotation como cuando agregas `[Required]` ejemplo:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Auto
    {
       [Key, ForeignKey("Conductor")]
        public int ConductorId { get; set; }
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        [MenorQue100]
        public int Millas { get; set; }
        public virtual Conductor Conductor { get; set; }
    }
```

de esta forma has creado una CustomValidation la cual no te permite agregar un Auto con mas de 100 millas. Espero te sea de ayuda

He editado mi respuesta pues como bien me ha recordado gbianchi, ya existe una DataAnnotation para este tipo de problema `[Range]` ejemplo;

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;   

public class Auto
    {
       [Key, ForeignKey("Conductor")]
        public int ConductorId { get; set; }
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        [Range(0,100, ErrorMessage = "Mayor que 100")]
        public int Millas { get; set; }
        public virtual Conductor Conductor { get; set; }
    }
```

de todas formas es bueno conocer la primera via si existe una caso en el que sea necesario utilizar un tipo de validación la cual no se encuentra en las DataAnnotations. Saludos

Comment: En realidad, si fuera el caso que estuviera usando DataAnnotations (que no lo aclara en ningun lado) y esta solo validando la entrada del lado del usuario, valdria mejor validar el rango [Range(0, 100, 
        ErrorMessage = "valor para {0} debe estar entre {1} y {2}.")]